# The const assertion seems that the type can't be assigned to the type any[] for the generic parameter

Tags: typescript

```
export const CHRONIC_CHANNEL_LEVELS = [
  { label: 'one', value: '1' },
  { label: 'two', value: '2' },
] as const;

export type ElementType<T extends any[]> = T extends (infer U)[] ? U : never;

type ChronicChannelLevel = ElementType<typeof CHRONIC_CHANNEL_LEVELS>['value']; // throw error
```

TSC throws an error:

```bash
Type 'readonly [{ readonly label: "one"; readonly value: "1"; }, { readonly label: "two"; readonly value: "2"; }]' does not satisfy the constraint 'any[]'.
  The type 'readonly [{ readonly label: "one"; readonly value: "1"; }, { readonly label: "two"; readonly value: "2"; }]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'any[]'.(2344)
```

The `const` assertion seems that the type can't be assigned to the type `any[]` for the generic parameter.

I want the type `ChronicChannelLevel` to be a union type `'1' | '2'`.

I know I can use `typeof CHRONIC_CHANNEL_LEVELS[number]['value']`, but I want to create a utility type like `ElementType` to get the element type from an array.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wMIAkBKB5AOQEkMB9bAQQIIFEAZUumgNXoGU4BeOAbQCg4cAN5wANgEMARsFEAuOAHIUwBQBo4AN3GiArsHkKAjArgBfVQOFipMgzADuENZu16DAJhPm+AXTjjURBR0AG4+PlBIWDgYAE8wYDgaUWAAW2BkGAAVeOAAHiy4UBgMgBNA8WRYnh8APi44QuKywIAKAEtkADNgKDgAVQBKGrgAfgG4eWRgDV6wvjiEuAwACygUdoRVyunROhmZBuS0jOzcvMXgCC7l3EISciwqWgYmVjo2Wp4FLV0VHzCQA)

Comment: you can just add `readonly` to `type ElementType<T extends readonly any[]> =`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By accepting that tuple/array and readonly tuple/array are fundamentally different types, we can make progress:

```js
export type ElementType<T extends (any[] | readonly any[])> =
  T extends (infer U)[] ?
  U :
  T extends readonly (infer U)[] ?
  U :
  never
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wMIAkBKB5AOQEkMB9bAQQIIFEAZUumgNXoGU4BeOAbQCg4cAPRDBY8QD0A-ALgBvOABsAhgCNgigFxwA5CmA6ANHABuyxQFdg2nQEYdcAL6HZCleq26YAdwhHT5lY2AEwOznwAunDKqIgo6ADcfHygkLBwMACeYMBwNIrAALbAyDAAKtnAADxlcKAwJQAmsQAUysiZPFEAPnBQwMqNKIqZ0R1dAJQAfFyytfVNrQCWyABmwFBwAKoTXXAygltwmnN1IA3IzX0DQ8gjcC0r65s7ewfbx7LIwCYbyVk5OAYAAWUBQSwQIPa30UdB+Gi4eQKxVKFRyVQBwAgqyBuEIJHIWCotAYTFYdDYUx4ACIzJZgNSInwRGJpEA)

...or by introducing a new type:

```js
export type ArrayType<T> = T[] | readonly T[]

export type ElementType<T extends ArrayType<any>> =
  T extends ArrayType<infer U> ?
  U :
  never
```

we can simplify the amount of inference and branching required for the conditional type

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wMIAkBKB5AOQEkMB9bAQQIIFEAZUumgNXoGU4BeOAbQCg4cAPRDBY8QD0A-ALgBvOABsAhgCNgigFxwA5CmA6ANHABuyxQFdg2nQEYdcAL6HZCleq26YAdwhHT5lY2AEwOznwAunDKqIgo6ADcfHygkLBwMACeYMBwFFBQypkAKtnAADzFAHxccMU8UQA+cFDAygAmKIqZdQ3JqdDwWTlwNIrAALbAyDClOZVwoDDT7bH5hSVl5crImVU1nLLFiyDLyKt5BUVzFQCWyABmwFBwAKo1MoKvcJqyyMAmZ7JYa5DAACygKFuCHBO3+ijoAI0tTGk2msy2IIgDzg2HwxDIlGo9EYLHYVR4ACIzJZgJSInwRGJpEA)